# Getting the Source/name of the EKCalendar

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working with IOS calendars, I wonder How Can I detect the source of the calendars. I mean detect the calendar is from Facebook, google etc.

I am using the calendar type but, it is not detail enough

```
   if (type == EKCalendarTypeLocal) {
        typeString = @"local";
    } else if (type == EKCalendarTypeCalDAV) {
        typeString = @"calDAV";
    } else if (type == EKCalendarTypeExchange) {
        typeString = @"exchange";
    } else if (type == EKSourceTypeMobileMe) {
        typeString = @"MobileMe";
    } else if (type == EKCalendarTypeSubscription) {
        typeString = @"subscription";
    } else if (type == EKCalendarTypeBirthday) {
        typeString = @"birthday";
```

Just to add more date, I am using

```
for (EKCalendar *thisCalendar in calendars) {
  EKCalendarType type = thisCalendar.type;
  EKSource* source = thisCalendar.source;
  DLog(@"title %@", source.title);
  DLog(@"Src Id %@ and title %@", source.sourceIdentifier, thisCalendar.title);
  DLog(@"Id %@", thisCalendar.calendarIdentifier);
```

But it's not really descriptive as how is on calendar iOS-builtin apps
any idea?

Answer (score 0):

`EKCalendar` objects have a `source` property of type `EKSource`. An `EKSource` object has two relevant properties for you: `sourceIdentifier` and `sourceType`. Now, `sourceType` is more or less the same as the type on `EKCalendar`, and therefore you might want to check the sourceIdentifier as it's just a string.

Checkout the [EKCalendar Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Reference/EKCalendarClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) and the [EKSource Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKSourceClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/EKSource) for detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
EKCalendar *calendar = ...
EKSource *calendarSource = [calendar source];
NSString *title = [calendarSource title];
```

Comment: Yes I do, but only get something like Src Id 6DFC6A45-2C16-4D4D-B96E-A98D50675706 and title Work