# ios Add Event to google calendar

Tags: iphone, ios, google-calendar-api

I have searching how to add event t users google calendar. In my project I have database with events(title,startDate,endDate etc). When user clicks sync button all this events should be add to users google calendar.

I downloaded api from [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Examples/CalendarSample). But its for MAC OS. Since I never worked on MAC OS application I cant understand how to use it in IOS app.

Please help me and tell which view controller to use asking for username and password, then login to google calendar service and add event in it.

Thank you.

I got http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/. But its difficult to understand. It takes username and password from preferences. Then gets calendars and adds events, but to add we need ticket and some more things. This code did some things.

In their add event method I wrote my own event object and tried to add that, but its not working. Here is the code:

```
- (void)insertCalendarEvent:(GDataEntryCalendarEvent *)event toCalendar:(GDataEntryCalendar *)calendar
{
    NSLog(@"adding event");

    GDataDateTime *time = [GDataDateTime dateTimeWithDate:[NSDate date] timeZone:(NSTimeZone*)[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

    GDataEntryCalendarEvent *newEntry = [GDataEntryCalendarEvent calendarEvent];
    [newEntry setTitleWithString:@"title"];
    [newEntry addLocation:[GDataWhere whereWithString:@"pune"]];
    [newEntry addTime:[GDataWhen whenWithStartTime:time endTime:time]];

  [googleCalendarService fetchEntryByInsertingEntry:newEntry
                                         forFeedURL:[[calendar alternateLink] URL]
                                           delegate:self
                                  didFinishSelector:@selector( insertTicket:finishedWithEntry:error: )];

}
```

My requirement is simple. I just want add my custom events to google calendar. Get calendar, get ticket, and in for loop add all my events.

Comment: Can anyone give urls of google calendar to authenticate user and then add event. I searched on google but did not found

Comment: Anyone tried this? http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/. Please help me in how to use this. When I execute that code in simulater I get option in setting asking for username and password. But how to do that in my app?

Comment: have u implemented google calendar in swift i need help

Comment: No. I did not try with Swift.

Comment: could u help me in objective c, could u provide complete code so that i can convert that one in swift

Comment: Sorry. That code was made for my earlier company and don't have access to it.

Comment: could u tell me where u have done it from

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using Google API and a new window where the user needs to be login again, you should use the [EventKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventClassRef/Reference/Reference.html), it's pretty easy stuff and you could sync to the Calendar where the user wants, not only Google cal.

Comment: Right, but it could be a Google Calendar, and then the EventKit will automatically sync it with Google calendar services and they can use non Google calendars also, so in my opinion it's way better.
Are you only want to sync to Google calendars?

Comment: how to get google calendar from Event kit and add event? EventKit has gives array of calendar, but I dint found a way to identify which is google

Comment: I found a similar problem like your, but it seems like there is no way to get Google only calendars for sure with EventKint
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189931/getting-the-source-name-of-the-ekcalendar

But reading the google api documentation, it say 
"The library is compatible with applications built for iOS 3 and later, and Mac OS X 10.5 and later."
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/

Or you can checkout the latest WWDC vid about iOS & OSX similarities: "Bringing Your iOS Apps to OS X"
https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/

Sorry, that was all what i can do :(

Comment: I tried google library. But difficult to understand. I have edited my question. Please can you help.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same requirement like yours to integrate google calendar and syncing events. I researched and found documentation from [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FExamples%2FCalendarSample) but I didn't understand it clearly, so later I found another good [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-working-with-google-calendars--mobile-19155) for accessing google calendar API's. You can try this for your requirement.

Comment: Do we have some Swift tutorials?

Answer (score 1):

As @Tuss Laszlo mentioned, the Google API Client library is your best option to add events only to a Google Calendar.  Google has a calendar sample in their example code.  See [the example](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Examples/CalendarSample/CalendarSampleWindowController.m) for the full implementation of adding calendar events.

Comment: I tried google library. But difficult to understand. I have edited my question. Please can you help.